# Send JSON object in setVlaue() of PropertyInfo class

Tags: json, soap, ksoap

When I pass a string value in `setValue()` it calls the web service perfectly. Instead, if I pass a JSON object it shows the "cannot serialize" error. I want to send the JSON object in `setValue()`. Could somebody help me?

```
SoapObject request1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo unameProp = new PropertyInfo();
unameProp.setName("param");
unameProp.setValue(data);
unameProp.setType(String.class);
request1.addProperty(unameProp);
allowAllSSL.allowAllSSL();

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);                  
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request1);
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 20000);
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line 4, i added toString() to solve the issue and the issue has been resolved.

**JSON object:**

```
JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
param.put("loginid", email.toString().trim());
param.put("password", password.toString().trim());
```

**line 4 :**

```
unameProp.setValue(param.toString());
```